# Click Gridview button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp datagrid with a remove button and I want to click on the button, enable the modal for the confirmation message and when okay is clicked in the modal, to call the normal C# code behind that would've been called if the modal was not there. I'm trying to achieve this using jQuery. Below is the code:

Gridview:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="btnRemoveProperty" runat="server" class="btnRemove" ClientIDMode ="AutoID" CommandName="RemoveProperty"> REMOVE <asp:linkbutton>
```

jQuery:

```
var btnConfirm;
var button;
$(".btnRemove").click(function () {
  if (btnConfirm == 1) {
    btnConfirm = "";
    return true;
  }
  else {
    button = $(this).attr('id');
    $("modal_delProperty").show();
    return false;
   }
 });

 $("#btnDelete.click(function () { //button inside the modal
      btnConfirm = 1;
      $("#" + button).click();  //is not doing anything
  });
```

The problem is that $("#" + button).click() is not doing anything even though it has the gridview button ID. It should have called the $(".btnRemove").click and then the code behind would've been called.

Comment: '.' instead '#'. '.' is used for class and '#' is for IDs

Comment: I store the id of the button in the gridview which is why I'm using '#'. The button should have the same btnRemove class as well which should trigger the $(".btnRemove").click function

Comment: ClientIdMode property is set to "AutoID" which means that the actual rendered ID of the control will be different. From Msdn, when it is "AutoID", the ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control.

Comment: isn't the id going to be the same as button = $(this).attr('id');?

Comment: Can you check putting an alert showing button value, just before clicking, if the right ID is being picked up?

Comment: yeah, the correct ID is picked up, but $("#" + button).click() does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#btnDelete").click(function () { //button inside the modal
  btnConfirm = 1;
  var el = $("#" + button); 
  $(el)[0].click();
  return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.I have done the same thing using asp button,its working and code behind event gets invoked.I have used the modal window with same id = btnDelete.

Mine

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnBeforeCnfrm" class="btnBeforeCnfrmCl" OnClientClick="return true;" ClientIDMode ="AutoID" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnBeforeCnfrm_Click1" />
```

Yours

```
   <asp:linkbutton id="btnRemoveProperty" runat="server" class="btnRemove" ClientIDMode ="AutoID" OnClientClick="return true;" CommandName="RemoveProperty"> REMOVE <asp:linkbutton>
```

Jquery

```
 $("#btnDelete").click(function () { //button inside the modal
      btnConfirm = 1;
      var el = $("#" + button); 
      $(el).click();
      return false;
  });
```